# Software Keyboard resizes layout even with windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"

Tags: android, android-view

I have the layout below, which when the software keyboard opens the bottom buttons move up and all get squished together.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:fillViewport="true">
 <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="#ffffff">    
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="10dip" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:src="@drawable/banner" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/erroremail"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:text="TEST"
                android:textColor="#D80000" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/email_logout"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:hint="Email address" >

                <requestFocus />
            </EditText>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/password"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:password="true"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:hint="Password" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnLogin"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
                android:background="@color/background"
                android:height="50dp"
                android:text="Sign In"
                android:textColor="#FFF"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/forgottenpassword"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:text="Forgotten password?" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dip"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/fbshare"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
                android:background="#3B5998"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/facebooklogo"
                android:height="50dp"
                android:text="Log in with Facebook"
                android:textColor="#FFF"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/get_started"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
                android:background="@color/background"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:height="50dp"
                android:text="Sign Up"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

        </LinearLayout>

  </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

I have set `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` in the manifest but this does not seem to have changed anything.

Testing on my Note 3 with android 4.3

Is there another way I need to force the view to not get pushed together and just have the software keyboard lay on top of the view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please put  `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustPan"` inside `activity` tag of `manifest` file

Comment: Then may be there is some different issue because its working for me always

Comment: found it was another issue in the java side so now works thanks!